# How can I print lines from file1 and file2 where columns 9 in file 1 is less than column 4 in file 2

Tags: python, bash, awk

I need help. I tried to no avail.
How can I print lines from file1 and file2 to my output file where column2 of file1 is same as column1 of file2, then $9 file1 >= $4 file2 && $10 file1 <= $5

file1

```
BG chr20   100.000 15      0       0       1       15      13242327        13242341        5.1     
BG chr2    100.000 15      0       0       1       15      70212527        70212541        5.1     
BG chr2    100.000 15      0       0       1       15      216745730       216745744       5.1     
BG chr1    100.000 15      0       0       1       15       6195235       6195335        5.1
```

file2

```
chr1    hg38_refGene    stop_codon      67093005        67093007        
chr1    hg38_refGene    CDS     67093008        67093604        
chr2    hg38_refGene    exon    216645730       216845744        
chr1    hg38_refGene    CDS      6095235      6395421
```

output

```
BG chr2    100.000 15      0       0       1       15      216745730       216745744       5.1  chr2    hg38_refGene    exon    216645730       216845744 
BG chr1    100.000 15      0       0       1       15       6195235       6195335        5.1    chr1    hg38_refGene    CDS      6095235      6395421
```

code

```
awk 'NR == FNR {A[$1] = $0; next} $1 in A {split(A[$1], T)} {if ( T[9] >= $4 && T[10] <= $5 )print A[$1], $0}' file1 file2 >output
```

Comment: [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your key from file 1 is field 2, not 1.

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR {a[$2]=$0; next} 
       $1 in a {split(a[$1],t); 
                if(t[9]>=$4 && t[10]<=$5) print a[$1], $0}' file1 file2 | column -t

BG  chr2  100.000  15  0  0  1  15  216745730  216745744  5.1  chr2  hg38_refGene  exon  216645730  216845744
BG  chr1  100.000  15  0  0  1  15  6195235    6195335    5.1  chr1  hg38_refGene  CDS   6095235    6395421
```

Comment: Thank you Karakfa, but I only got only the first line of the output.

Comment: test with the sample data you posted, this is the result of my run with the same input files.  Perhaps your line endings are different or your data may not be identical in structure to the one posted

Answer (score 1):

`join` is designed for this.  The caveat is that join requires two sorted input files (this is often a pitfall for first time users).

So, try this:

```
join -1 2  <( sort -k2,2 file1 ) <( sort file2 )
```

Here's the output:

```
chr1 BG 100.000 15 0 0 1 15 6195235 6195335 5.1 hg38_refGene CDS 6095235 6395421
chr1 BG 100.000 15 0 0 1 15 6195235 6195335 5.1 hg38_refGene CDS 67093008 67093604
chr1 BG 100.000 15 0 0 1 15 6195235 6195335 5.1 hg38_refGene stop_codon 67093005 67093007
chr2 BG 100.000 15 0 0 1 15 216745730 216745744 5.1 hg38_refGene exon 216645730 216845744
chr2 BG 100.000 15 0 0 1 15 70212527 70212541 5.1 hg38_refGene exon 216645730 216845744
```

You can then use awk to change the column order if you'd like.